# jquery toggle and nested form

Tags: javascript, jquery, nested-forms

for some reason the following is not working. What's wrong?

I'm just trying to toggle visibility of element. I have multiple links with class 'variant_description_link' on the page since I add form through js as well. All I want is find the closest 'variant-description' block and toggle visibility.

```
$('.variant_description_link').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.variant-description').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Seems correct, post more code and perhaps create a fiddle illustrating the issue.

Comment: Can we see some of the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the elements are being called by jQuery before they're actually available in the DOM.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.variant_description_link').click(function() {
        $(this).toggle();
    });
});
```

[(working example)](http://jsfiddle.net/DsQCD/)

Comment: Your 'on' syntax is wrong (see correct fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ecmSz/, your code in the fiddle is in onLoad).

Comment: Thanks @CodyBonney & Benjamin. I updated fiddle to show what I'm trying to accomplish. it should toggle textarea 1 when click on link 1 and so on http://jsfiddle.net/DsQCD/2/

Comment: yep, excellent except it doesn't work with my rails app. I guess there is something between the DOM and nested_form js. Anyway, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

> I have multiple links with class 'variant_description_link' on the page since I add form through js as well.

sounds like you need to use `on` delegated event for click..if the form you are adding through js contains the `variant_description_link`

try this

```
 $(document).on('click','.variant_description_link',function() {
   $(this).closest('.variant-description').toggle();
});
```